# For which complex numbers $z$ is $\Re(z)+\Im(z) < |z|$?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I'd like to find all complex numbers for which $\Re(z) + \Im(z) < |z|$ where $z=x+iy$.

Since $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, I assumed the following:

$x+y<\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \implies (x+y)^2 < x^2+y^2 \implies x^2 +2xy +y^2 < x^2+y^2 \implies 2xy < 0 \implies xy < 0.
$

However, this would mean that the above would be true for all numbers in the 2nd and 4th quadrant. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually any point satisfying $x+y<0$ will satisfy the above inequality, so it is true for points in 3rd quadrant too

Comment: I saw that $L=C\{z=x+iy:(x≥0)∧(y≥0)}$ which would include the 3rd quadrant as well - I don't know why because that wouldn't satisfy $xy<0$ or would it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $|z|\ge 0$ for all $z\in \mathbb C$

So if $x+y\le 0$, then the inequality is trivially true for all $x+y\le 0$ except the origin that is all points lying on or below the line $y=-x$ except $(0,0)$

Now if $x+y\ge 0$, then you can square both sides to get $xy\lt 0$, which is true precisely when $x$ and $y$ both are non-zero and of opposite signs.  (You have considered only this part). That is 2nd and 4th quadrants.

So your final range of values of $(x,y)$ is $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:xy\lt 0\}\cup \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}: x+y\le 0\}$, that is, all points except in the first quadrant. Here first quadrant includes origin, positive x and y axis also.

Comment: I like this explanation. I missed that $|z| \ge 0$ in my calculation

Answer (score 1):

You cannot square an inequality in general. So your answer is wrong.

The region conists of all points below the line $y=-x$, the part of the fourth quadrant between $y=-x$ and the $x-$ axis as well as the part of the second quadrant between the line $y=-x$ an the $y-$ axis. The union of these parts is exaclty all points excluding he closed first quadrant.

Comment: That is all except the closed first quadrant, isn’t it?

Comment: Right. Thank you.  I have added that final statement. @MartinR

Comment: `You cannot square an inequality in general` Right. Thanks! But how do I proof your answer algebraically?

Comment: @j3141592653589793238 You can square the given inequality when $x+y \geq 0$. You have to consider the case $x+y<0$ separately. In this case the inequality automatiacllly holds so all points with $x+y<0$ are included.

Answer (score 1):

$z=re^{i\theta}$ for $r\in\Bbb R^{+},\theta\in \Bbb R$. Then
$$\operatorname{Re}z+\operatorname{Im}z<|z|\iff r\operatorname{cos}\theta+r\operatorname {sin}\theta<r\iff \operatorname{cos}\theta+\operatorname{sin}\theta<1$$

Answer (score 0):

The *equation*

$$x+y=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

is strictly equivalent to

$$xy=0$$ provided you keep the condition $$x+y\ge0.$$

This describes the boundary of the first quadrant (positive semi-axis), which separates the areas

$$x+y\gtrless \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

By testing with $(1,1)$ we see that this quadrant is excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Like others with polar coordinates, let $x=r\cos2t, y=r\sin2t$  where $0\le t<\pi$

We need $$\cos2t+\sin2t<1$$

Using [Weierstrass](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Weierstrass_Substitution#Proof) Substitution  with $u=\tan t$,  $$1-u^2+2u<1+u^2\iff2u(u-1)<0\iff0<u<1\implies0<t<\dfrac\pi4$$